# Can we load 20 k PDFs in attachment object like we load data using dataloader

Tags: data-loader, data

Our client has a requirement to load his agreement PDFs & word docs inside salesforce account -> agreement -> notes & attachment.
I am looking for fastest solution like Dataloader insert but i dont know how i can use dataloader to load pdf in attachment object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use Data loader for Attachments import:

[Uploading Attachments using Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=loader_attachments.htm&language=en_US)

NOTE: The big idea is your CSV file should have a column mapped to import with an actual file path on your workstation.